# got a question about mysql service in WSL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm installed a package named mariadb-server clinet in WSL `Sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

after that,I'm try to start the service,it shows this to me`mariadb: unrecognized service`

and my linux version is ubuntu 18.04 LTS

this is my first question in stackoverflow,hope you guys understand my question,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you start it with:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

See this for a reference: https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I'm tried this command : 'sudo service mysql start' before,an it responsed：* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                 No directory, logging in with HOME=/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//.cache’: Permission denied
-su: 19: /etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh: cannot create //.cache/wslu/integration: Directory nonexistent

Comment: Does it seem that there are no related documents in the target path?